# Python PyQT QPainter. minimum painting code. Painter not active problem

Tags: python, pyqt, qpainter

I tried to implement a minimal code for generating a graphic in PyQt, see below:

```
WIDTH = 870#mm
HEIGHT = 1170#mm

DPI = 400
INCH = 25.4#mm
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    # GUI    
    window = QtGui.QWidget()
    
    
    scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    

    view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(window)
    view.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing,True)#HighQualityAntialiasing
    view.setScene(scene)
    view.setFrameStyle(0)
    view.setFixedSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT)


    # create 
    graphicItem = QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(0,0,10,10)
    scene.addItem(graphicItem)
    
    #save to file
    image = QtGui.QImage(int(WIDTH/INCH*DPI), int(HEIGHT/INCH*DPI), QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
    painter = QtGui.QPainter()
    painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing,True)
    targetrect = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, int(WIDTH/INCH*DPI), int(HEIGHT/INCH*DPI) )
    
    scene.render(painter,targetrect)
    painter.end() 
    
    image.save('example.png')
        
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Why is this not working? I get Error:

```
QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
```

What is the quickest way to generate a graphic in PyQt without having to create widgets with overwritten paintEvents?

Comment: [`QPainter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html) expects a [QPaintDevice](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintdevice.html) which you haven't specified, you should either specify it in the constructor or through [`painter.begin(QPaintDevice)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#begin).

Comment: Change to `painter = QtGui.QPainter(image)`. Also: 1. if you just want to draw a scene, you don't need a QGraphicsView; 2. if you just want to draw something that will be saved on an image file, you don't need a QGraphicsScene at all, just use the functions of QPainter like `drawEllipse`, `drawPath`, etc (which is exactly what basic shapes of QGraphicsScene do).